# Cyclic Python imports freeze Tkinter app

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, progress-bar, ttk

I'm making app that uploads video to server, so I've got an START.py file which makes Tkinter window and handles all Tkinter widgets and another one (which is being run by START.py file), upload_video_to_server.py, which obviously, uploads video to server. I'm doing this using Threading so app doesn't freeze while it's uploading, so I want to make active ttk.ProgressBar which will track upload. I managed to get needed informations (file size and already uploaded size) from upload_video_to_server.py but problem is that ProgressBar is inside START.py. After googling and many tries, I saw that cyclic imports ask for importing inside function for various reasons, so I did that like this:

START.py

```
def chProgressBarValue(value):
    progress().prog_bar["value"] = value
    print "ProgBarValueChanged to: ", prog_bar["value"]

def chProgressBarMax(max):
    progress().prog_bar["maximum"] = max

def progress():
    global prog_bar
    print "prog bar is being made"
    prog_bar = ttk.Progressbar(
            app, orient="horizontal",
            length=200, mode="determinate",
            value=5,
            max=15
            )
    prog_bar.pack(side=TOP)
    prog_bar.place(x=380, y=395)
```

upload_video_to_server.py

```
def printTotals(transferred, toBeTransferred):
    print "Transferred: {0}\tOut of: {1}".format(transferred,     toBeTransferred)
    import START
    START.chProgressBarMax(toBeTransferred)
    START.chProgressBarValue(transferred)
```

But after first print of transferred data information, new Tkinter window shows up and freezes/crashes whole app (uploading works like a charm without importing START.py). Here is a pic of log + problem (second empty Tkinter windows SHOULDN'T be made!)

[image: PIC]

Comment: tkinter is not frezee ! wait your process end. Use thread, event etc.

Comment: @dsgdfg i already said I'm using threading. Everything works well before I import START.py.

Comment: First, it seems strange that `progress()` create new `ProgressBar` at each call (and that the version you posted does not return anything...). I bet the new Tkinter window is consequence of invoking "Tk()" somewhere at START module-level code.

Comment: @FabienAndre How do I create ProgressBar properly then? I don't want it to be created at beggining of the app, it should be made only after user starts upload. I just checked by printing debug messages if new Tkinter window is made by START.py, and every check was false positive. If you want, I can edit my post with full codes from both .pys, it will be opensource project anyways (or pastebin/pastie is okay if you prefer).